# Is this number computable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

My question is based on this answer:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/458768/292477

> Let $T$ be the Turing machine which looks for a proof of a
>   contradiction in ZFC. If ZFC is consistent, then whether or not $T$
>   halts will be independent of ZFC. (Indeed, if not, then this would
>   contradict Gödel's incompleteness theorem!)
>   (Zhen Lin)

Given now this program that prints a number (print doesn't include a newline):

```
print "0."
for i = 0 to infinity:
    halted = execute_i_steps_of_the_given_turing_machine_and_return_true_if_it_halted()
    if halted:
        print "1"
    else:
        print "0"
```

I think it should be computable, but I'm not sure if the definition of the number is even valid.

Maybe someone could help me here? Is the number computable?

Thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, this number is computable.  Your definition of it is an algorithm for computing its digits.

More generally, you should be aware that not knowing what a number's value is has little to do with whether the number is computable.  For instance, define a number $n$ as follows.  If ZFC is consistent, $n=1$.  If ZFC is inconsistent, $n=0$.  This number is certainly computable: either the program that just outputs $1$ computes it, or the program that just outputs $0$ computes it.  It doesn't matter that we can't determine (in ZFC) *which* of these programs is the right program to use: either way, there exists a program that works.

Comment: Hm, so I don't know if this is possible, but what if the consistency of ZFC is undecidable? Wouldn't that make *n* uncomputable?

Comment: @Mehrdad No. Eric's answer did not assume that the consistency of ZFC is decidable.  If it's undecidable, then we don't know which of the two programs "print 1" and "print 0" computes $n$, but one of them does. To say "$n$ is computable" just means that there is an algorithm computing it; it does not mean that we know what the algorithm is, nor that there is a proof (in your favorite formal system) that the algorithm is correct.

Comment: As I always note, the proof that $n$ is computable is highly contingent on either the assumption of consistency of ZFC (in which case $n=1$) or the excluded middle. For some reason, there are still some skeptics of the excluded middle out there...

Comment: @AndreasBlass: I think our confusion is what you mean when you say "compute *n*". Do you mean "compute the set of potential values for *n*", or do you mean "compute *n* itself"? Because if the consistency of ZFC is undecidable, then I don't know how an algorithm could decide whether to print 0 or 1 without deciding what *n* is.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Saying that an algorithm computes $n$ is a very weak statement; particularly, the algorithm doesn't have to have anything to do with how we defined $n$. It's purely a statement about the output of the algorithm, not what it does internally. One of the two programs `print 0` and `print 1` computes $n$; we don't need to figure out which.

Comment: @Mehrdad Concerning "I don't know how an algorithm would decide whether to print 0 or 1 ..."  The algorithm "print 0" makes that decision quite easily.  The algorithm "print 1" also makes that decision easily. These are the only two algorithms involved in my comment and in Eric's answer. You're probably thinking about more complicated algorithms that involve working with the axioms of ZFC. Such algorithms might indeed have difficulty deciding what to print, but they're not relevant here.

Comment: @user2357112: Let me give a different example to illustrate what I mean. Instead of ZFC, let's say I want a program to give me the first digit, in binary, of Chaitin's constant with respect to some fixed encoding (the digit *after* the leading zero, obviously). Are you going to claim that every digit must be 0 or 1, so therefore every digit is computable? That seems wrong to me, because it seems neither would be more "correct" than the other (regardless of whether or not we would *know* which one is correct). If you're not claiming this, then how is it different than our ZFC case?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Indeed, every digit is computable. That doesn't mean that there's one program that can take an index and compute that digit; it means that for every digit, there is a program that computes it. Chaitin's constant itself is not computable; for that, we'd need the take-an-index-and-compute-that-digit program.

Comment: @user2357112: Yes, I'm not having trouble with the "all-the-digits" part. What I'm finding bizarre is that *neither* program computing the first digit might actually be *correct* regarding it, so to say one of them is computing that digit it is quite... jarring. You need to know *one* of them is correct (even if you don't know which one) but how do you even know one of 0 or 1 must be more correct than the other?

Comment: @Mehrdad: How could neither of them be correct? Do you think that the binary digit you want to compute might be something other than 0 or 1? Are you working under a nonstandard model of logic?

Comment: @user2357112: I don't know if this is equivalent to excluding the law of the excluded middle (I'm not a mathematician), but I'm basically saying that if a binary number is (colloquially) "unknowable, even in approximation" (which is, hand-wavily, what Chaitin's constant seems to be, or at least that was my intention in choosing it) then it seems wrong to claim that one of two programs must somehow "know" the first digit, and that *you* merely don't know which one does. Do you see what's bothering me? If it's unknowable, *both* would be wrong in their claims.

Answer (score 14):

Of course, this value is either $0$ or $2^{-n}$ for some $n$, and all of those numbers are computable, so this number is computable. (Assuming the result is treated as binary.)

If base $10$, then this value is either $0$ or $9^{-1}\cdot 10^{-n}$ for some $n$, and any rational number is computable.

Comment: technically this program doesn't halt when the TM halts. Once it prints a 1, it will continue printing 1's, making it more than 10^-n. Of course this doesn't change the computability of it

Comment: I didn't say anything about halting. :) @Cruncher

Comment: Oh I know. But the number will have infinite trailing 1's after the first 1. so 10^-n is not accurate as that implies 0's after the 1.

Comment: I didn't say $10^{-n}$. I said $9^{-1}\cdot 10^{-n}$, which is $0.0000\dots01111\dots$. @Cruncher

Comment: Oh. Carry on then :)