# What is the exact difference that makes Chaitin's number uncomputable while this other number (from another post) computable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, chaitin-constant

This is a follow-up to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2324434). In the post, the user defines a number $x$ that is $1$ if $\textsf{ZFC}$ is inconsistent and $0$ otherwise. By virtue of the fact that $x$ is either $0$ or $1$, it is computable. Now I am trying to compare this to the case of [Chaitin's number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChaitinsConstant.html) $\Omega$, which is uncomputable.

Why exactly is $x$ computable and $\Omega$ is not? As someone in the link said,

> More generally, you should be aware that not knowing what a number's value is has little to do with whether the number is computable.

This makes sense, but then why does this statement not apply to $\Omega$? What exactly am I missing that makes $x$ and $\Omega$ dissimilar?

Comment: The difference is that $\Omega$ has an infinite number of digits. Any number $x$ with a finite number of digits is computable, because the algorithm to compute it is just "print(x)".